# CodeIgniter automatic logout user

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using the code below for automatic logout after 1 minute of inactivity. Now I have to use this code in CodeIgniter. I researched on google but did not found any solutions to my question. Even I checked on SO but not able to understand.

1) I just need a help that where should I added auto logout code?

2) How do I modify this code in CodeIgniter?

3) Should I add this code in the controller?

4) Should I update the login time every time till user in the system?

Sorry for the lots of question, I am learning the Codeigniter Framework.

```
<?php
//on pageload
session_start();
$idletime=60;//after 60 seconds the user gets logged out
if (time()-$_SESSION['timestamp']>$idletime){
    session_destroy();
    session_unset();
}else{
    $_SESSION['timestamp']=time();
}
//on session creation
$_SESSION['timestamp']=time();
```

I am adding the login time into the database while user login.

```
 $data_login= array('emp_id' =>$result->id ,'login_time' =>date("Y-m-d H:i:s", STRTOTIME(date('h:i:sa'))));
 $this->db->insert('tbl_current_login',$data_login);
 $last_id=$this->db->insert_id();
 if (!empty($last_id)) {
 $active_user_session = array('id' =>$last_id,'access_role'=>$result->access_role);
 $this->session->set_userdata('active_user_session',$active_user_session);
 return $result;
```

Let me know if need more explanation.

Comment: This won't work, and I doubt you'll be able to find a solution using PHP. PHP is server side, that means once this code is ran, it doesn't do anything else.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton, This is the PHP code which I found on Github, now I have to use same code or else any other code to log out if the user inactive using CodeIgniter.

Comment: you should use ajax with javascript or jquery to call this on a controller/function every 60 seg to execute this code

Comment: @Geomorillo, Thanks for the reply, Can you assist me with the code?